# Unable to use Hash Angular and aws cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am using angular to build my app and AWS Cognito for the access(login etc) ..
I use the  hash (useHash=true) but I can not configure Callback URL having hash(#) in it.
it is not allowing us to configure the URL with hash.

And for this, when I launch my angular app, first I get the login page of AWS Cognito but after login, I have my page constantly refreshing and when I set the useHash= false it works.
But I need to put useHash= true, it works fine

Do you have a way to solve this problem?